# Compile and execute C program in Python using Windows

Tags: c, python-3.x, windows

I need to iteratively edit, recompile and run a C program called `sum_subgiants.c` through Python (using Spyder on Windows). I am using a python code that has previously worked on my colleague's Mac. I am a novice with python and have no experience with C.

There is a `makefile` and all relevant files stored in the same folder as `sum_subgiants.c`. I have tried

```
subprocess.run('make sum_subgiants', shell=True)
```

to compile and then

```
subprocess.call('sum_subgiants', stdin=input_file, stdout=output_fh, shell=True)
```

These commands do not appear to do anything. Any help in terms I can understand would be much appreciated.

I notice that there is no `make` command on Windows, which explains the error. Is there an alternative command that would work on Windows?

Should I expect `subprocess.call` to run easily after I have sorted out the `make`?

Comment: Debug it one step at a time. Specifically, does the `make` step succeed or not? No point looking at the second step if the first step fails. Also, have you successfully run `make` manually on the terminal for that project? Lots of things you can do to debug this further which would aid you and this question.

Comment: The make command works when run on Mac terminal. The make step does not succeed in python on windows.

Comment: Yes, but does the `make` work in Windows outside python? No point diving into python if your Windows environment is not set up correctly to run `make`. That is, debug your problem systematically to find the first point of failure. Unlike Mac and Linux `make` is not natural to Windows.

Comment: No it doesn’t. Thanks for your advice. As I see it I could install chocolatey to help make the file. Or is there an alternative command that will work in windows?

Comment: [`cmake`](https://cmake.org/) is arguably one of the best ways to manage cross platform builds. But there is a bit of a learning curve - not huge but also not insignificant.

Comment: Should I expect the subprocess.call to run easily after I have sorted out the make?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, everything is difficult.

- You need to install a C compiler on the Windows machine.
- You need to install `make` on the Windows machine.
- Depending on what is done in the `makefile`, you might need to install other tools as well.

You could consider installing MSYS2 and MinGW, which provide a Unix-like environment for Windows.

But I would question the whole procedure: Why is it necessary to dynamically build a C program at run time? This is going to be so complicated that looking for an alternative solution might be preferable.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I installed gcc compiler and attempted to compile through the windows command prompt but there are many errors returned which I assume are related to the makefile as you mentioned. Now that I realise the complexity of the task I will likely compile the multiple variations of the program that I need in Unix before running my python script. Is there a simple way to execute the already compiled C program in windows?

Comment: From Python, `os.system('executable')`.